# Azure - WebSphere MQ V7.5 client?

Tags: azure, ibm-mq

I am trying to find out if installing the WebSphere MQ V7.5 client within a Azure Worker Role or a server running Windows 2012 R2 on the IaaS platform is supported.   I cannot find much on the IBM web site.  My guess is I am going to have to contact someone within IBM but do not know witch group to contact.

Comment: Have you looked at this page: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27027462#Windows_tab. Windows 2012 R2 has been listed as a supported operating system.

Comment: Yes I have looked at that document and I do see Windows Server 2012 R2 listed but I was hoping to find some specific guidance around Azure.  Azure at a very simplistic level is based on hyper-v.  I also cannot find much on hyper-v support. Everything I have seen talks about VMware.

Answer (score 0):

IBM Provides Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) for Amazon Web Services and promotes it fairly heavily.  If they had the equivalent for Azure I'm sure they would also promote it openly.  There doesn't appear to be much online though you can extend on-premise MQ to Azure via some tecniques but that's not truly MQ in Azure.